# How to populate a long text field from map values?

Tags: trigger, list, map

I'm trying to populate a long text field with phones from many contacts, but I don't know how to do it. I want to populate a field called "Authorized Contacts" with all phone numbers returned from a map whenever a case is inserted or updated.

```
trigger getAuthorizedContacts on Case (before insert, before update) {

Set<Id> CaseIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Case getIds : Trigger.New){
    CaseIds.add(getIds.Contract_Case__c);
}    

Map<Id, Junction_contact_contract__c> aContacts = new Map<Id, Junction_contact_contract__c>([SELECT Contact__r.Phone 
                                                                                                       FROM Junction_contact_contract__c
                                                                                                       WHERE Contract__c IN: CaseIds AND 
                                                                                                       Contact__r.RecordType.Name = 'Authorized Contact']);   
if(aContacts.size() > 0 ){
    for(Case a : Trigger.New){
        a.Authorized_contacts = aContacts. ;
    }
 }  
}
```

Could you guys please help me to solve this? If you guys have any other suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the "aContacts" map values and create a string containing all phone numbers, then you can use it anywhere.

```
String phones = '';
for(Junction_contact_contract__c junction : aContacts.values()) {
   phones = phones + ' ' + junction.Contact__r.Phone;
}

if(aContacts.size() > 0 ){
    for(Case a : Trigger.New){
        a.Authorized_contacts = phones;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't thank you enough!